# Change emit socket in setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, setinterval

I have a problem issuing a socket from another browser/tab that is in a countdown (setInterval)

I have the following script

This code allows me to understand all the people who have connected on the platform

**server.js**

```
var nicks = new Array();

function usuarios(socket){
socket.emit('usuarios', {nicks: nicks});
socket.broadcast.emit('usuarios', {nicks: nicks});
}

function nick(socket){
socket.on('nick', function(data){

    var nick = data.nick;

    var variable =  nicks.filter(function(hero) {
        return hero.user == data.nick.user;
    });

    if(variable.length==0){ //Nuevo
        nicks.push(nick);
        socket.nick = nick;
        socket.emit('nick', {correcto: true, nick: nick});
        usuarios(socket);
    }else{//Existe

        socket.emit('nick', {update: true, nick: nick});

    }

})
}
```

**front.js**

```
    var timer;

    function myTimer(reset) {

        clearInterval(timer);

        timer = setInterval(function() {

            countdown--;

            var nick = {user: actualuser, time: countdown};
            socket.emit('nick', {nick: nick});

            if (countdown == 3000) { //Reset count.
                countdown=3600;
                var nick= {user: data, time: countdown};
                socket.emit('nick', {nick: nick});
            }
        }   , 1000);

    }

socket.on('nick', function(data){

});
```

The socket will start emitting the next count every 1 second

```
["nick",{"update":true,"nick":{"user":"1","time":3542}}]
```

All this works, but the problem I have now is that if a person enters different browsers, the countdown that is handling each session is not restarted but instead continues its process.
example

- Chrome TAB 1: Countdown = 3450
- Chrome TAB 2: Countdown = 3032
- Chrome TAB 3: Countdown = 3978

Each time I update the tab (Refresh) the counter is reset to 3600 but only the current tab

When the 3000 second condition is met, the counter is reset on all tabs

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you need exactly,

if you want to keep the same time for all, you need to put your interval function in you server node.js and emit a reset of your timer if needed, and when a new user is connected, just send the actual countdown to it.

You can listen new user connected with :

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // where io = require('socket.io')(http),
})
```

Comment: Yes, but the setinterval runs only and exclusively in the browser session, if I open another tab or browser it runs a completely different setinterval.

What I want to do is that if the person enters a different browser than the current one, the counter will be reset globally (Socket)

Each connected user will have their own counter.